# How to get total nginx requests of yesterday from prometheus?

Tags: monitoring, devops, grafana, prometheus

This might be a stupid question, but I couldn't find any way to find all HTTP requests to my nginx proxy for last 1 day.

I tried `sum_over_time(nginx_request_status_count{status_code='200'}[1d])` but where will I feed the time range? In this case, `yesterday to today`

But, as you can see above, I get only 200's summation. Even if I use `=~ "2.."` I'll get error as the output have multiple status codes.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `sum(increase(nginx_request_status_count[1d]))` which is roughly the total number of requests in the past day,

Comment: Hi, @brian. Thanks for your response. But is it possible to get the total count for an arbitrary time range? like 2 days before or last week?

Comment: Yes, set the time of the query to the end of the relevant range.

Comment: to me this still gives a graph. Is it possible to get a single scalar value?